Can someone please help figure out the mistake in my solution to this problem
I am not able to figure out any mistake in my solution to the given problem but the answer is coming out to be different than the given answer.
THE PROBLEM:
Jerry starts at 0 on the real number line. He toss a fair coin 8 times. When he gets heads, he moves 1 unit in the positive direction. When he gets tails, he moves 1 unit in the negative direction. The probability that he reaches 4 at sometime during the process is a/b, where a and b are relatively prime positive integers. What is a+b? (For example, he succeeds if his sequence of tosses is HTHHHHHH)
MY SOLUTION:
Case 1:
E1=Event where first 4 consecutive tosses are heads
P(E1)=1/16
Case 2:
E2=Event where first 6 consecutive tosses have 1 Tails (so that Jerry can reach point 4 after 6 tosses), but first 4 tosses are not all heads (to exclude the cases already counted in E1)
P(E2)=4/64=1/16 {4 ways of choosing a Tails in the first 4 trials divided by the total cases}
Case 3:
E3= Event where the 8 tosses have 2 Tails (so that Jerry can reach point 4 after 8 tosses), but first 4 tosses have at least 1 tail (to exclude the cases already counted in E1) and first 6 tosses have 2 tails (to exclude the cases already counted in E2)
P(E3)=(4*5/2)/256=5/128 {(4 ways of choosing 1 Tails from the first 4 tosses) * (5 ways of choosing a heads from the remaining 5 tosses from the first 6) /(2 as the two tails are identical)}
Probability = P(E1)+P(E2)+P(E3)=1/16+1/16+5/128= 21/128
21+128=149
But the given answer is 151



Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

This question has already been answered https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807424/probability-of-reaching-net-4-heads-when-tossing-coin-8-times

@DrM Thank you for finding the linked duplicate.  When you do find a duplicate, please vote to close, select duplicate as the reason, then provide a link to the original question.

In case 3, if the second tail is the 5th or 6th throw, you are still dividing it by 2 as if you could have chosen them in the opposite order despite the restriction on your first choice of tail. The tails are not always identical if you place restrictions on only one of them. Instead think of it as {TTHH}{HHHH} and {THHH}{TH}{HH} for 6+4*2=14 possibilities.

In case 3, there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways of selecting exactly two tails in the first six tosses, of which exactly one does not have at least one tail in the first four tosses, namely HHHHTT, so there are $\binom{6}{2} - 1 = 15 - 1 = 14$ favorable cases.
